# Replace missing value with N/A for multiple columns at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda, missing-data

I want to replace the missing value (or blank ' ') of a column with 'N/A'. I have tried below code but probably making some mistake or not using the right method.

```
df2['test_edited'] = df2['test'].map(lambda x: 'N/A' if x.empty() )
```

or

```
df2['test_edited'] = df2['test'].map(lambda x: 'N/A' if x == ' ' )
```

This is the error I am seeing:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What I have tried before: 
I have used if-else with lambda before and probably that is more standard way but in this particular case I only want an If-Then statement type of usage. Because I only need to replace the blank or missing value but keep the other values of the column as it is. For example in the below example I want to replace age 42 with 0 but I want to keep the other age values intact, which doesnt work if you are using if-else statement

[image]

```
dfx['Age'] = dfx['Age'].map(lambda x: '0' if x == 42 else 1)
```

[image]

So my problem is:
1. Is it possible to use only an If-then type of statement inside lambda
2. How do I execute the same operation on multiple columns at the same time ? For example in the below case, if I had test1 test2 test3 etc and I want to take care of all of them in one line.

The missing values are basically blank and looks like this

[image]

Comment: `df2['test_edited'] = df2['test'].map(lambda x: 'N/A' if x == ' '  else x)` you mean?

Comment: Yes. I think that is it. Now how to do the same for multiple columns - I mean if I use df2['test', 'test2', 'test3'].map(lambda ) I will get error .

Comment: something like `df2 = df2.replace('N/A', np.nan).fillna('')`

Comment: I tried below code but its not working. fill_list = ['Age', 'Age_Group']
       dfx[fill_list] = dfx[fill_list].replace('N/A', np.nan).fillna(' ')

Comment: I think this works - dfx[fill_list] = dfx[fill_list].replace(' ', 'N/A') .

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you had N/A which you wanted removed. Didn't know it was the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define a list of columns that you want to fill missing values and then apply `fillna` on that subset:

```
fill_list = ["A", "B", "C"]
df2[fill_list] = df2[fill_list].fillna("N/A")
```

Comment: I tried the code and I guess ideally it'd have worked but because my missing values are represented as blank or '  ' like this, the code didn't have any effect. I have updated my post at the bottom. I ran below code without any success fill_list = ['Age', 'Age_Group'] 
dfx[fill_list] = dfx[fill_list].fillna("N/A")

Answer (score 0):

To fill missing values generally we use [.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html)

Like so for a single column:

```
df2['test_edited'] = df2['test'].fillna('N/A')
```

In case you have multiple columns and want to make a copy of each column in which the NaN values are replaced with 'N/A', as Yilun Zhang writes in his answer, you can use fillna on multiple columns at once as well.

```
col_list = ['test', 'customer']
nan_replaced = ['test_edited', 'customer_edited']
df[nan_replaced] = df[col_list].fillna('N/A')
```

Comment: But it isn't NaN, it's "N/A"

Comment: Are you sure? Because the first sentence in the question is `I want to replace the missing value (or blank ' ') of a column with 'N/A'`

Comment: @tobsecret  you are right. I want to replace '   ' with 'N/A'